# Shallow routing next js syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

In next js I am trying to change route without refresh page.

I am using this syntax which I don't like:

```
  Router.push(
   `/statistics?entityId=${id}&type=${entityType}&provider=${serviceProvider}`,
   `/statistics?entityId=${id}&type=${entityType}&provider=${serviceProvider}`,
   {
    shallow: true
   }
```

Is there a way to have this syntax?

```
Router.push('/statistics', { countryCode: countryCode, country: selectedCountry }, { shallow: true });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes but the syntax is a bit different. The second parameter for `Router.push` can be a `string` or an `UrlObject`.

For example, if you want to the URL to be `/statistics?countryCode=1&country=US` you can use `Router.push` like this with shallow routing

```
Router.push('/statistics', {
  query: {
    countryCode: 1,
    country: "US"
  }
}, { shallow: true })
```

The same thing can also be achieved if the page isn't dynamic and  you want to provide the first argument as `UrlObject` including the `pathname`. For example,

```js
Router.push({
  pathname: "/statistics",
  query: {
    countryCode: 1,
    country: "US"
  }
}, undefined, { shallow: true })
```

You can refer the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#with-url-object) for more details.

Comment: Hey, this method is sending infite GET request in my network tab. Why is it happening ? Can you please help me? Attaching my code below for your reference.



 <Button onClick={() => {
        router.push({
          pathname: `/course/${id}`,
          query: {
            code
          }
        }, undefined, { shallow: true })
      }}> Edit</Button>

Comment: @sugandhgoyal I would suggest posting a separate question with more details so your issue could be understood better by others.